# I need to draw Rectangle with Simple Fill Symbol

Tags: arcobjects, c#, layouts

I need to draw this rectangle on layoutview :

[image: I need this :]

I try this but it doesn't work. How can I draw this rectangle  ?

```
        IPoint p1 = new PointClass();

        p1.X = 9.9936; p1.Y = 5.8777;

        IPoint p2 = new PointClass();

        p2.X = p1.X; p2.Y = p1.Y + 2.62;

        IPoint p3 = new PointClass();

        p3.X = p1.X + 0.152 ; p3.Y = p1.Y;

        IPoint p4 = new PointClass();

        p4.X = p3.X; p4.Y = p3.Y + 2.62;

        IPointCollection ring = new RingClass();
        ring.AddPoint(p1);
        ring.AddPoint(p2);
        ring.AddPoint(p3);
        ring.AddPoint(p4);

        IRgbColor color = new RgbColorClass();
        color.Red = 255; color.Blue = 28; color.Green = 20;

        ISimpleFillSymbol simpleFillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass();
        simpleFillSymbol.Color = color;

        IElement element = new PolygonElement();
        element.Geometry = ring as IGeometry;  // I try this.
        element. ???  // I need to apply symbol on this element. but it hasn't symbol property

        IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IPageLayout pageLayout = new PageLayout();
        pageLayout = mxdoc.PageLayout;
        IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = pageLayout as IGraphicsContainer;
        graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);


        IActiveView activeView = pageLayout as IActiveView;

        activeView.Refresh();
```

This solution has problem at :

```
    IElement element = new PolygonElement();
    element.Geometry = ring as IGeometry;  
    ((IFillShapeElement)element).Symbol = (IFillSymbol)simpleFillSymbol;
```

@Berend's solution is working..

Comment: Are you saying it does not draw at all or it does not draw in the symbol you want it? Looking at your code you create the element, you create a simple fill but you do not apply it and you simply add the graphic to the page layout and I assume it has used some default colouring?

Comment: When I run this Add-in, ArcMap is crash..(gives an error). You right, I created polygon element, I created simple fill but I can't apply it..I'm trying to draw this with RingClass now.. But I couldn't yet..

Comment: Try using a PolygonClass instead of a RingClass? It would be helpful if you edit your question and add the error message.

Comment: @Umut, what is the error you get (On which line)? Please include it in your question

Comment: These look like errors from visual studio, not some .net run time error (I could be wrong)? I see you are using 10.3 have you upgraded visual studio recently? You should be using visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd prefer a shorter version:

```
private void AddRectangle()
{
    var element = new RectangleElementClass
    {
        Geometry = new EnvelopeClass {XMin = 9.9936, YMin = 5.8777, Width = 0.152, Height = 2.62},
        Symbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass {Color = new RgbColorClass {Red = 255, Green = 20, Blue = 28}}
    };

    var mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
    var graphicsContainer = mxdoc.PageLayout as IGraphicsContainer;
    graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);

    (mxdoc.PageLayout as IActiveView).PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, element, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Berend It's working ! shorter and good solution..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
((IFillShapeElement)element).Symbol = (IFillSymbol)simpleFillSymbol;
```

Comment: Thank you for solution but it didnt'k work :/ It has an error at : "         IElement element = new PolygonElement();                     element.Geometry = ring as IGeometry;                                    ((IFillShapeElement)element).Symbol = (IFillSymbol)simpleFillSymbol; "